# GCD - always returns 1

Tags: c++

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could take a look at my code and explain to me why the greatest common divisor always returns as 1. I am using Euclid's algorithm to find the gcd.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    while (b)
    {
        int tmp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = tmp;
    }
    
    return a;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Enter first integer: ";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    
    cout << "Enter second integer: ";
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    
    int gcd(int a, int b);
    
    cout << "The greatest common divisor is: " << gcd << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int gcd(int a, int b);` in `main()` is a function declaration - which tells the compiler there is a function that accepts two arguments, but does NOT call it.   `cout << "The greatest common divisor is: " << gcd << endl;` does not call the function either - it tests if `gcd` is a non-null pointer (which it always is).   Change those two lines to `cout << "The greatest common divisor is: " << gcd(a,b) << endl;`

Answer (score 2):

Your calling of function is not correct. You are trying to redefine a function inside a function which is not possible, To declear a function inside a function use `lamda functions`. You can call the function inside `cout statement` as i did in the code below.

*Note :* `using namespace std` is never considered a good practice try to avoid it as much as possible.

Happy Coding.

```cpp
#include <iostream>


int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (b) {
        int tmp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = tmp;
    }

    return a;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter first integer: ";
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "Enter second integer: ";
    int b;
    std::cin >> b;


    std::cout << "The greatest common divisor is: " << gcd(a, b) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you confuse declaration and definition. Declaring a function inside another is possible, thats why OPs code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing your GCD as a variable. You should do something like this:

```
int gcdCalc = gcd(a, b);

cout << "The greatest common divisor is: " << gcdCalc << endl;
```

Also since most numbers are relatively prime to one another, the GCD will a be 1 a lot of the time. Try it with 48 and 2, you should get the GCD as 2.